# Drupal 7/Zen - How do you move the header (field_image) image above the title on a page?

Tags: 7, theming

How do you move the header (field_image) image above the title on a page?

**Drupal 7/Zen Theme**

This seems like it would be a simple thing to do. I've been messing around with trying to accomplish this by doing a few things suggested on other websites but cannot seem to get it to work.

I've tried editing the page.tpl.php file but that messes up my homepage.

I'm trying to do this without using panels or any other module.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the page.tpl.php template file, but avoid it gets used for the front page, just:

- Create the page--front.tpl.php file from the current page.tpl.php file
- Edit the page.tpl.php file to move the image above the title

In this way, page--front.tpl.php will be used with the front page, and page.tpl.php will be used with the other pages.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Zen? And is this a background image, or just an image in the header?

For a fixed width theme, you can insert a background image into the #header with the following CSS:

```
#header {
  margin: 0px 0 0 0;
  height: 193px;
  background: transparent url(images/header.png) no-repeat top center;
}
```

The Zen 5 markup is a little leaner, and you probably have to add a #header-bgimg div in your page.tpl.php file just inside the regular #header div. Then you can add a header image like this:

```
#header-bgimg {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 33.3%; /* Responsive Scaling: 333px/1000px = 0.3333 */
  background-image: url(../images/header.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

This time I used additional directives to make it a responsive header image. If you don't use the additional wrapper, you collide with some of the Zen 5 CSS.

Placing other objects in your header might require a #header-inner wrapper just inside the #header-bgimg div.

Comment: There is no need to create a separate page--front.tpl.php template for a different bg image. Do it in CSS with .front #header-bgimg {...}

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question. You don't mean header image, maybe you mean a field/CCK image in the node? I often turn off the Page title, and write my own as an <h2> ... </h2> which I can put below the image.

Answer (score 0):

page--[node-type].tpl.php may help.

What I mean is if you have made a page.tpl.php which achieves the desired functionality then simply renaming this file to page--[node-type].tpl.php will mean that this template will not interfere with your homepage.

Comment: You should really expand on this.  As it stands, it's not really an answer to the question - more of a starting point for an answer.